# Fault Calculations on Multi-Family Dwellings

Tags: electrical

I was told that when doing fault calculations from a meter pack on a multi-family dwelling, that the fault calculations should be done using the distances from the SES to first panel, then from the first panel to the second panel, and so on (like doing a calculation in series).

However, it occurred to me that it may be necessary to do the fault calculations from the first meter to the first panel, second meter to the second panel, and so on (basically doing the calculations in parallel).

Having trouble finding an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

### You only need to compute the fault current for the shortest feeder

The answer to this question is you don't need to do *either* computation -- it'd be silly to assume that the impedance of a longer wire to 60Hz AC is lower than that of a shorter wire at the distances in question, so you simply need to do the fault current computation for the *shortest* meter-to-panel feeder, especially for the simple case where you have series ratings between the subpanel breakers and the unit main breaker at the meter.